# Malformed href using {url} for slider link

Tags: channel, fields, links

I have a slider at the top of my page using this HTML:

```
<div id='top_slider'>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="home" limit="1"}
        <!-- <div class="arrow_left white" onclick="slide('left')"></div>
        <div class="arrow_right white" onclick="slide('right')"></div> -->
        {home_promo_slider}
            {if active == 'y'}
                {if row_count == 2}
                    <div class="arrow_left white" onclick="slide('right');stopAutoSlide();"></div>
                    <div class="arrow_right white" onclick="slide('left');stopAutoSlide();"></div>
                {/if}
                <div class='slide'>
                    {if url != ''}<a href="{url}">{/if}
                    <img class="fullscreen_img" src='{image}' />
                    {if url != ''}</a>{/if}
                </div>
            {/if}
        {/home_promo_slider}
</div>
```

I want to link the images to a URL specified in the Homepage Content using a channel field. The problem is that this only works for internal links currently. If I enter "store" into the URL field it correctly takes me to http://mywebsite.com/store, but if I enter an external link such as http://google.com, the href becomes malformed and spits out this:

```
<a href="&lt;a href=" http:="" google.com"="">http://google.com</a>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Channel Preferences for this Channel for the *Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links* option. It sounds like you have it set to "Yes" and this is causing the malformed HTML.

Control Panel Location: Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Preferences

[image]

[Documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#automatically-turn-urls-and-email-addresses-into-links)